# Include libraries or external stylesheets in Express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am building a todo app using express framework on node server...I have an index.ejs file as the starting point for my application, In the same folder I put my jquery.min.js file, when I try to include the jquery file as

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My app fails to load it, when I see the network in my chrome it looks for

```
https://localhost:3000/jquery.min.js
```

How do I load the file ??

PS: I am accustomed to loading scripts via **cloud.google.com** by placing the url in the src tag , But I want my application to load faster by this approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should create a ./public folder for static files.

add this line to your app.js above all your routes:

```
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Then just use this in index.ejs:

```
<script src="/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: My COde [github link](https://github.com/mudassir0909/CoffeeScript_Todo_App/tree/version/using_backbonejs) the line I added in src/configuration.coffee & my index.ejs is in src/views...This gives me the error "Reference Error: path is not defined"

Comment: You have to `require` the `path` module. `var path = require('path');`. The `path` module is documented http://nodejs.org/api/path.html